# this program gives me an infinite menu (do-while)

Tags: java, do-while

I'm new here. I am trying to run a program which always gives me an infinite menu loop whenever i try to execute it. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void show()throws IOException
 {
                   BufferedReader z=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                     int ch;
                     input();
                     calculate();

                         System.out.println(" 1.Print the names of Employees having more than average salary");
                         System.out.println(" 2.Find the maximum and minimum gross salary ");
                         System.out.println(" 3.To find the net salaries of employees in ascending order");
                         System.out.println(" 4.To print the name of employee having the longest name");
                         System.out.println(" 5.To find the reverse names of the employees");
                         System.out.println(" 6.To find the reverse of employee's name");
                         System.out.println(" 7.Exit");
                         System.out.println("Enter your choice");
                         ch=Integer.parseInt(z.readLine());


                         switch(ch)
                         {
                            case 1:calc_avg();
                            break;
                            case 2:max_and_min();
                            break;
                            case 3:sort();
                            break;
                            case 4:vowel();
                            break;
                            case 5:longest();
                            break;
                            case 6:reverse_name();
                            break;
                            case 7:
                            System.out.println("Close");
                            break;
                            default:System.out.println("Wrong choice ! ");
                            }
                            }
                            while(ch>=1&&ch<=7);
```

}
}

This always gives me an infinite loop. How do i fix this ?

Comment: Your example is not complete, but from what you have posted: while(ch>=1&&ch<=7); causes infinite loop

Comment: Thanks for the reply. how do i fix it ?

Comment: you have forgot to paste the code or what ...where is loop begining?? where is default statement break??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Yeah I pasted the whole code and they said something about the formatting. I am sorry for being a noob. But I have posted the default or break statement, even the do while loop. Need I paste anything more ?

Comment: @Chirag: Basically, you will need to wrap code starting from `ch=Integer.parseInt(z.readLine());` and also define exit condition. Something like this: `if(ch<=0){return;}`

Comment: Please format your code correctly (indents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do properly ;)

```
public void show()throws IOException {
        BufferedReader z=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int ch=0;
        input();
        calculate();
        System.out.println(" 1.Print the names of Employees having more than average salary");
        System.out.println(" 2.Find the maximum and minimum gross salary ");
        System.out.println(" 3.To find the net salaries of employees in ascending order");
        System.out.println(" 4.To print the name of employee having the longest name");
        System.out.println(" 5.To find the reverse names of the employees");
        System.out.println(" 6.To find the reverse of employee's name");
        System.out.println(" 7.Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter your choice :");
        ch=Integer.parseInt(z.readLine());
        while(!(ch>=1&&ch<=7)){
            System.out.println("Wrong choice ! Please enter a good choice :");
            ch=Integer.parseInt(z.readLine());
        }

        switch(ch){
        case 1:
            calc_avg();
            break;
        case 2:
            max_and_min();
            break;
        case 3:
            sort();
            break;
        case 4:
            vowel();
            break;
        case 5:
            longest();
            break;
        case 6:
            reverse_name();
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("Close");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check it to "accept as good answer" so, and you're welcome ;)